# Allure Report unknown unknown - NoN%

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, allure

I am a newbie to allure and Pytest. I have created test cases in Ppytest framework. For reporting, I am using allure. when I execute the allure serve  command report shown as NoN%. Is there any plugin missing?

I did not understand where I went wrong. Can anybody assist me to resolve this issue?

When I run,

```
pytest --alluredir=Reports
```

The JSON files are created instead of XML. Then I executed allure generate allure-reports inside the Report folder. When I run allure serve allure-reports, report shown as Non% even though 5 test cases passed.

Report Image : - 
[image]

Pytest report image : -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to create test reports with allure, you need to run pytest with alluredir argument as you said.

`pytest --alluredir=results`

After that from the same folder where you ran pytest run:

`allure serve results`

this command will create a report folder inside your /tmp dir and will serve reports at a random port from localhost.

If you want to find out more about allure commandline run:
`allure --help` or [Read the docs](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_report_generation)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by installing the missing JDK 8 on my machine and provided the JAVA_HOME path in the JDK section of the Global Tool Configuration in Jenkins.

Dashboard-->Manage Jenkins-->Global Tool Configuration-->JDK

Comment: Use italics (e.g. `*<path>*` gives: *<path>*) for paths.

Answer (score 0):

Xml files are generated in older library **pytest-adapter-allure**
If you have installed  **allure-pytest** you will get json files.
Getting Nan%  in reports could be because of path  provided does not contain the json files required for displaying the report

**steps for generating and viewing reports in allure-pytest**

1. create empty folder for allure report in your framework.(ex. reports)
2. run test with alluredir specified
   pytest --alluredir test/testname
   3.check the reports directory in the framework has populated with .json file files after test execution
3. In Command Prompt run
   allure serve